# JupyterLab Extension Manager Not Working on Mac

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyter-extensions

I am new to JupyterLab and trying to use it to help me learn Python.  When I go to the extension manager, I get the attached [Screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tECZ.png).

I can enter search criteria (after approving the policy) but only get the "Error searching for extensions: Error: Unhandled error" error in the discovery panel.

I have read the installation documentation but need help as I don't seem to have missed anything obvious.  I have installed node.js + uninstalled the jupyterlab packages.  I have reinstalled using.

> sudo pip3 install jupyterlab

No errors during installation.  I am using a Mac Silicon 2 with macOS Sonoma installed. I have Python 3.12 running, and everything else, besides the extension manager, seems good.  I have also tried accessing it with Firefox and Safari (but there seems to be no difference).

Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/14965, see the workarounds described in the issue

Comment: Sorry for the slow response (I have been down with COVID for a few days).  Thanks for this. I spent hrs trying to work it out, and this fixed it.